# Aligning comments in a bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How would I go about rearranging the comments in a file so that all the comments are aligned on the rights 2 spaces after the longest line?

Comment: Do any of the answers here work for you? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/how-can-i-easily-indent-inline-comments/16869#16869

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with sed. If you want to parse all things like quotas, you should write program which will proceed with parse as bash do that.

Comment: What. should the alignment column be? Here, it's 2 spaces past the longest line.

Comment: Shouldn't line 6 in the output say `echo ${#A[@]}                 # first # doesn't begin a word`, not `echo ${#A[@]}                 # don't change first #`?

Comment: @engo473 : I don't think that this can be done without using a parser for bash, in particular because of lines which have a `#` embedded in a string, because it may be difficult to find the end of the string. Think of, for instance, `echo "   #  \"  #  " foo`. You would have to recognize that there is no comment in this line.

Comment: @engo473 After editing the input, you have not changed the output and do not match.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in sed using a trick. 
The main problem is counting the number of escape characters in sed taking into account bash dodges. We temporarily replace # with a unique character (I used ___) for lines that are not a comment, and finally undo the replacement.

I use a substitute IF for sed in form /pattern/{s/source/destination/}

```
sed -e $'/^#.*$/{s/#/___/g};/echo \" /{s/#/___/};/echo \\\\\\\\" /{s/#/___/};s/ #/\001#/;s/^$/\001/;s/___/#/g' zzz.txt | column -ts $'\001'
```

**EDIT:**

I made a small correction so that 2 # in 1 line would not be moved. Now **the result is exactly like the example**.

input data:

```
# begins with #
  # begins with space    
A=1
B=(bax qux)  # comment
  C=(2 3)  # don't change indentation
echo ${#A[@]}  # first # doesn't begin a word
echo "  # not a comment"
echo \"  # comment\"
echo \\"  # not a comment\\"
```

output data:

```
# begins with #
                              # begins with space
A=1
B=(bax qux)                   # comment
  C=(2 3)                     # don't change indentation
echo ${#A[@]}                 # first # doesn't begin a word
echo "  # not a comment"
echo \"                       # comment\"
echo \\"  # not a comment\\"
```

This is a single-line script and for simple applications such as the example is sufficient. If there were a lot more additional rules, I would be inclined to set macros in m4 or similar solutions.

Comment: I think this would fail for lines, where `#` does **not** denote the start of a comment.

Comment: @user1934428 Check. For the input data from the example, the result is exactly as in the requirements. There may be other cases, then you have to add them to the regex.